# Single webdriver instance of chrome get url multiple times will timeout

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, timeout

Python: When I initialized a webdriver instance of chrome, and call the get method multiple times, everything is ok until the times beyond 300 or more, the webdriver will throw timeout exception, but the url of get is acceptable from another webdriver instance. Why the timeout happened? What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks for your answer~

Comment: So you have 300 open windows?

Comment: I can't recognize the difference between `window` and `tab`. Does the chrome open one window or tab with get once? Or refresh the url within one tab? If first, why not crash exception but timeout exception?